# What is the radius 1 in unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

I mean is this radius is 1 cm/ 1 inch long
and most of definitions say unit circle has radius of 1 unit ,what is this unit

Comment: It’s just a $unit$. Saying it’s a meter, centimeter, or whatever won’t affect anything since all lengths and calculations will be relative to your unit of choice.

Comment: It is the same unit as all measurements along your axes.

Comment: In geometric constructions where things are to be measured, it is generally presumed that we have a segment of length $1$ against which other lengths are compared.  There is no specified unit.

Comment: You choose the *unit of measure* and the unit circle will be he circle with radius $1$ according to that unit of measure.